# Compiling TypeScript to JavaScript using Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am new to NodeJS and TypeScript and I want to begin by setting up my project folder. I already have my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny" : false
},
"files": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]}
```

and package.json

```
    {
      "name": "crm",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

This is my simple directory structure:

```
    crm/
     |-src/
       |- main/
          |- app.ts
```

when I compile it using the tsc command, I expected that the compiled directory will be

```
    crm/
     |-build/
       |- main/
          |- app.js

     |- src/
        |- main/
           |- app.ts
```

but the result is

```
    crm
     |- build/
        |- app.js

     |- src/
        |- main/
           |- app.ts
```

there is no main folder that is created.

I dont know if the problem is on tsconfig.json or in the tsc command

Comment: you want to maintain folder structure in `build` or compile inplace and put it in `src`?

Comment: i want it the ouput directory in build folder

Comment: ok.. added the answer..try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set

`"outDir": "./build",`

in your **tsconfig.json** and no `rootDir`.
Check compilerOptions [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Set the required output build path.

```
"outDir": "./build",
"rootDir": "./src"
```

You will get

```
crm
 |- build/
    |- main/
       |- app.js
```

Src: [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5134)